# Regex match with bleed

Tags: php, regex

I have a paragraph of text. I want to match a word and select 10 words preceding it and 10 words following it alongside the keyword itself.

So far I've reached the following which selects the 30 characters before and 30 characters after. How could it be converted so I can actually select 10 words before and 10 words after?

```
.{1,30}?keyword.{1,30}
```

example:

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum
has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not 
only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

and I want to match `standard`. The regex should return the following match

```
printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define "word" is a "string of non-whitespace characters", then this seems to do the trick:

```
((\S+\s){,10})(standard)((\s\S+){,10})
```

Demo: http://rubular.com/r/a3SsQZbCkP

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
(\w+\s+){1,10}\s*keyword\s*(\w+\s+){1,10}
```